# gem install pry FilePermissionError

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rubygems, pry

When I tried to install pry on terminal, it keeps telling me

```
$ gem install pry
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 
directory.
```

I've tried to update gem, using homebrew to install ruby. but still get the same error.

Comment: Run `brew doctor` and see if it warns you about anything related to permissions. Also check if the `ruby` and `gem` you are running really come from Homebrew and not from the system Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Common Practices when something says what you don't have permission to perform an action:

1. Try to execute the command with `sudo` prefix (`sudo gem install pry`).
2. Execute the command as `root` (Not recommended due to potential issues).